# Getting magento2 soap api error ProcedureNotPresent in magento2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, soap-api-v1

I have integrated magento soap api with 3rd party to update magento order status and shipment.

After upgrading magento 2.1.16 to 2.3.0 it stoped working and throughing error.

I’m debugging the process of updating Magento to mark the order as shipped. I have 2 mechanisms to do this:

The first is to call the salesShipOrderV1Execute method, I only need to supply the orderID. When I do this I get a ProcedureNotPresent error (see below):

```
POST www.xyz.com/soap/all?services=salesShipOrderV1 HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer f65z18lpyc6xmtbnjqjhqxt4eiiuuok5

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="salesShipOrderV1Execute"

Host: www.xyz.com

Content-Length: 359

Expect: 100-continue

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><salesShipOrderV1ExecuteRequest xmlns="xyz.com/soap/default?services=salesShipOrderV1"><orderId xmlns="">7638</orderId></salesShipOrderV1ExecuteRequest></s:Body></s:Envelope>

Error Response:

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error

Server: nginx

Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2019 15:57:55 GMT

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 299

Connection: keep-alive

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.19

Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=e3o3trsifo4rg44jbkp1idvlbs; expires=Tue, 27-Aug-2019 16:57:55 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.xyz.com; HttpOnly

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>rpc:ProcedureNotPresent</env:Value></env:Code><env:Reason><env:Text>Procedure not present</env:Text></env:Reason></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>

I have a second option, I can call the ‘salesShipmentResponsitoryV1Save’, for this I supply more details:

POST www.xyz.com/soap/all?services=salesShipmentRepositoryV1,salesShipmentManagementV1,salesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1 HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer 8rk8onpw1e92hbga9cmcqr2krb4lfw3f

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="salesShipmentRepositoryV1Save"

Host: www.xyz.com

Content-Length: 702

Expect: 100-continue

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: Keep-Alive

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><salesShipmentRepositoryV1SaveRequest xmlns="xyz.com/soap/default?services=salesShipmentRepositoryV1%2CsalesShipmentManagementV1%2CsalesShipmentTrackRepositoryV1"><entity xmlns=""><billingAddressId>14458</billingAddressId><customerId>14884</customerId><orderId>7638</orderId><shippingAddressId>14458</shippingAddressId><items><item><name>Sizzix Big Shot Tool Caddy</name><sku>661077</sku><orderItemId>10202</orderItemId><qty>1</qty></item></items></entity></salesShipmentRepositoryV1SaveRequest></s:Body></s:Envelope>

I get the same response error response.

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error

Server: nginx

Date: Tue, 27 Aug 2019 15:57:13 GMT

Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8

Content-Length: 299

Connection: keep-alive

X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.19

Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=krrgdpe7l4v12tolbr30cbmgbv; expires=Tue, 27-Aug-2019 16:57:13 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=www.xyz.com; HttpOnly

Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate

Pragma: no-cache

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><env:Body><env:Fault><env:Code><env:Value>rpc:ProcedureNotPresent</env:Value></env:Code><env:Reason><env:Text>Procedure not present</env:Text></env:Reason></env:Fault></env:Body></env:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you get this solved? Did other soap calls give a ProcedureNotPresent as well? Or was it just this call? We upgraded our Magento to 2.3.4 and suddenly all soap calls gave a Procedure not present error. It turned out some rewrites were disabled during the upgrade and it took us hours to find out. To see if it is a rewrite problem, try using index.php in your call and your soap body like this:

```
www.xyz.com/index.php/soap/all?services=salesShipOrderV1
```

notice the "/index.php" before the "/soap/". If that does work, then check your rewrites!